# How to create a response that returns an array

Tags: php, xml, arrays, return, response

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert array to SimpleXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397036/how-to-convert-array-to-simplexml)

I'm trying to figure out how I can modify a script that does some SQL stuff so that at the end of the script, return either a straight up array or an array encoded in XML format to the client.

What is the best way to do this? I'm pretty sure you can't just return a variable, but it needs to be encoded with something like HTML or XML.

(Also, I need the client to wait until the array has been received in order to avoid storing files on the server).

Comment: How are you calling the script? What is the client? How do you want to process the data in the client?

Comment: What does your array look like?

Comment: This is far too vague to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple way to return an array is [encode it as JSON](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) but this might not be sufficient for your goals. However, take a look on the options provided by JSON. Tutorial is here: http://www.sencha.com/learn/legacy/Tutorial:Creating_JSON_Data_in_PHP

If you want XML, please have a look on this thread: [How to convert array to SimpleXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397036/how-to-convert-array-to-simplexml)